# Google chart stacked bar get key name when onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

```js
    google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'bar'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['DATA', 'L', 'P'],
   ['PCX',  18, 21],['PCG',  131, 34],['PCO',  9, 3],['PGD',  441, 269],['PAH',  1, 1],['POD',  8, 5],['PCT',  80, 180],['PDD',  1, 7],['PZZ',  3, 8],['PKK',  461, 580],['PBI',  494, 248],['PKI',  2, 5],['PKL',  5, 1]  ]);

  var options = {
   isStacked: 'percent',
   legend: { position: 'top' },
   chartArea: {
    left: 40,
    width: '100%',
    height: '75%'
   },
   vAxis: {
    minValue: 0,
   },
   hAxis: {
    textStyle: { fontSize: 7 }
   }
  };


  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('DataChart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
  
   
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

  function selectHandler(e) { 
   var selection = chart.getSelection();
     if (selection.length > 0) {
    var mydata = data.getValue(selection[0].row,0);
        alert(mydata);
        //i want get key data L when klik stacked data L or P when klik stacked data P, because i want to send data
        
    chart.setSelection([]);
     }
  }
    }
    
    
      $(window).resize(function () {
      drawChart();
    });
```

```css
svg > g > g:last-child { pointer-events: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="DataChart" ></div>
```

Hello, i have a create stacked bar from google chart plugin, i want to get data when i'm click slice bar (red or blue) when i click  red i get data "P" if i click blue get data "L" this demo in [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pedoyxy/14/)

i'm already get data name data like PCX,PCG,PGD etc  but i want get data "L" if click blue color and get data "P" when click red color.  Help me thank's

Comment: you can use `<>` for demo

Comment: this js fiddle for demo => https://jsfiddle.net/2pedoyxy/14/

Comment: i doubt people will visit and external link just for your demo.well good luck :)

Comment: done, i'm already attach code snipped then you can answer my question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the column label, use data table method --> `getColumnLabel(colIndex)`
pass the `column` property from the selection...

```
function selectHandler(e) {
  var selection = chart.getSelection();
  if (selection.length > 0) {

    // get column label
    var colLabel = data.getColumnLabel(selection[0].column);

    var mydata = data.getValue(selection[0].row,0);
    console.log(colLabel + ': ' + mydata);
    chart.setSelection([]);
  }
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  $(window).resize(drawChart);
  drawChart();
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['DATA', 'L', 'P'],
    ['PCX',  18, 21],['PCG',  131, 34],['PCO',  9, 3],['PGD',  441, 269],['PAH',  1, 1],['POD',  8, 5],['PCT',  80, 180],['PDD',  1, 7],['PZZ',  3, 8],['PKK',  461, 580],['PBI',  494, 248],['PKI',  2, 5],['PKL',  5, 1]    ]);

  var options = {
    isStacked: 'percent',
    legend: { position: 'top' },
    chartArea: {
      left: 40,
      width: '100%',
      height: '75%'
    },
    vAxis: {
      minValue: 0,
    },
    hAxis: {
      textStyle: { fontSize: 7 }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('DataChart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

  function selectHandler(e) {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    if (selection.length > 0) {
      var colLabel = data.getColumnLabel(selection[0].column);
      var mydata = data.getValue(selection[0].row,0);
      console.log(colLabel + ': ' + mydata);
      chart.setSelection([]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="DataChart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In google charts document,

"If both row and column are specified, the selected element is a cell. If only row is specified, the selected element is a row. If only column is specified, the selected element is a column."
(https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events)

In your demo, when clicking blueBar(L), selection[0].column will be 1 and the other(redBar(P)) will be 2.

Thus you can get P/L in selectHandler

```
var data = ['DATA', 'L', 'P']
function selectHandler(e) { 
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    if (selection.length > 0) {
        var temp = selection[0].column
        console.log(data[temp]) // temp = 1 will be 'L'; temp = 2 will be 'P'
    }
}
```